# What is the difference between “ renewal ” and “ resumption ”?

Tags: word-choice, differences

Cambridge English Dictionary explains these as

> *renewal* : a situation in which something begins again after having stopped for a period of time e.g. Pharmaceutical shares also benefited from the renewal of interest in growth stocks.
>
> *resumption* : the start of something again after it has stopped

I dont really see the difference.

Comment: I would say that 'renewal' is a fresh reviving after a time of cessation, like summer after winter.. 'Resumption' indicates that whatever it was that stopped, has started again, as it was before. Like a noise.

Comment: Something is _resumed_ when it is started up again after a break, often a planned one. _Renewal_ suggests something _new_, for example a revival of interest, an organisation restarted with different ideas.

Comment: In law, for example, if a contract is renewed, it means that it is extended after its original term has expired. "resumed" would indicate that contract performance restarts after an interruption (as caused by a force majeure event).

Comment: Please look these words up in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/) (Oxford), where you can usually find several examples of any defined word in sentences as example uses. This can contribute to better grasp of how the words are used. Sometimes differences are solely which word is more often used in certain contexts or constructions.

Comment: There is an overlap between the meanings of 'renewal' and 'resumption' but 'resumption' usually indicates a shorter break and less final closing down than 'renewal'. For instance there would be a 'resumption' of production at a factory after a lunch break, a holiday or a strike because the period of inactivity was comparatively short and the factory was ready to be started up at any time during that period. However a "renewal" of production at the same factory would occur if it had been closed down for years and all the machinery had been removed.

Comment: Your registration, licence, insurance policy etc. are renewed, not resumed, but your vacation period is over, and you now have to resume your work/ resume your daily routine after a bout of illness; here it is not renewed.

Comment: You can't resume your library book, with the related sense of resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cambridge Dictionary, as quoted, clearly shows the differences and the similarities between these two words.

To summarise the meaning of resumption is limited to

> the start of something again after it has stopped

Whilst Renewal relates to:

> renewal noun (CONTINUE); the act of making an official document, agreement, or rule continue for more time:

> renewal noun (START AGAIN); the act of starting again or starting to do something again:

> renewal noun (IMPROVEMENT); a process in which something improves or is improved after being in a bad condition :

Only the second meaning is similar to that of resumption. Even this use is not exactly the same. *Start again* can equally relate to starting over (new approach, design, etc) as it can to resuming a paused process. However, "*resumption*" has been defined as a re-start not "*starting over*".

I would also add that I believe that most people using renewal meaning "*start again*", would actually be using it to relate to **starting over** or as it would be termed in the UK "**starting afresh**".

---

start over [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/start-over)— phrasal verb with start verb US

(UK **start afresh**)

to begin to do something again, sometimes in a different way: